# Having one thread acquire multiple objects from a shared list

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a list of available employees, categorized by their profession (e.g "Programmer", "Tester"),
the amount of each available profession is stored in a Semaphore.
To accomplish a certain task - each done in a different thread -  a list of professions if given (e.g. 2 "Programmer", 1 "Manager")
and the task should get them in an all or nothing fashion - if all are available you take all the ones in the list, otherwise wait for everyone to be available.

I have accomplished this by limiting the access for the list itself using BlockingQueue, Semaphore or just lock it manually.

What I'm asking is what is the proper way to do it, and if possible, how to still have the release method be available to other threads.

Comment: I wonder if you could just implement this as a Scheduler that has a `schedule` methods that takes resource requirements, then returns a future. Internally, and *not* concurrently, it maintains what's basically a Gantt chart of who's doing what. When a task's start time is reached, the work can be dispatched. This might just mean acquiring semaphores, or it could mean sending work to real worker threads. It does mean there's a queue, and it shows just how painful real-time scheduling can be.

Answer (score 1):

You need a monitor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) to accomplish your task.
It can be realized with a java.util.concurrent.Lock (ReentrantLock) and many Condition's on the lock.

Comment: What do you mean by many conditions on the lock? I used a lock, and the condition was "wait until everyone is available" , is that what you mean? If so, why is this method better than Semaphore or BlockingQueue?

Comment: I meant one condition per type of resource in the list of available resources. So that the amount of threads woken up when a resource is released is lower. You also need a proper policy to avoid starvation.

Comment: Wouldn't this have starvation issues where simple tasks could be blocked because more complex tasks already acquired a lock on the resources?

Comment: Of course it will, but the chance of starvation is bundled with the problem statement. You need to add first a "policy" to the problem statement, then adapt the algorithm to ensure its fulfillment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem really got my interest. Quite a fun project. Here's a basic implementation that seems to work for your description. See the bottom for a runnable example to go along with it. It's fairly limited (doesn't support negative acquires, no timeout options, etc etc), but it has just enough to use it, and you could easily extend upon it as necessary.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

/** Represents a group of semaphores identified by distinct strings
 * Supports basic acquire and release operations. Other operations could be added as necessary
 * @author MPatashnik
 */
public class SemaphoreGroup {

    /** The total number of permits available to this, as it was constructed */
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> permits;

    /** The semaphores in this group, by their identifier */
    private final HashMap<String, Semaphore> semaphores;

    /** The semaphore monitoring use of operations in this SemaphoreGroup */
    private final Semaphore operationLock;

    /** A map of threads to permits they currently own */
    private final HashMap<Thread, Map<String, Integer>> threads;

    /** Set to true to see printing output of threads acquiring and releasing */
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    /** Creates a SemaphoreGroup. All semaphores are initialized as unfair.
     * @param permits - the Number of permits for each identifier string
     */
    public SemaphoreGroup(Map<String, Integer> permits) {
        this.permits = new HashMap<String, Integer>(permits);
        operationLock = new Semaphore(1);
        semaphores = new HashMap<String, Semaphore>();
        threads = new HashMap<Thread, Map<String, Integer>>();
        for(String s : permits.keySet()){
            semaphores.put(s, new Semaphore(permits.get(s)));
        }
    }

    /** Attempts to acquire the given permits
     * @param permits                   - the permits to acquire
     * @throws InterruptedException     - see Semaphore.acquire()
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException - If one of the permits this wants to 
     *                                      acquire is an unrecognized string, or any of the
     *                                      permit acquisition counts is negative
     */
    public void acquire(Map<String, Integer> permits) 
            throws InterruptedException, IllegalArgumentException{
        try{
            operationLock.acquire();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Acquired " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : permits.entrySet()){
                Semaphore s = semaphores.get(e.getKey());
                if(s == null){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Permit Name " + e.getKey() + " Not in " + this);
                }
                if(e.getValue() < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Permit Value " + e.getValue() + " Must be positive");
                if(s.availablePermits() < e.getValue()){
                    operationLock.release();
                    if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Released " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    //Not enough permits - wait on semaphore until someone releases, then try again
                    synchronized(operationLock){
                        operationLock.wait();
                    }
                    acquire(permits);
                    return;
                }
            }
            //All semaphores ok. Do acquiring and exit
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : permits.entrySet()){
                semaphores.get(e.getKey()).acquire(e.getValue());
            }
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            //Update information of this thread owning permits
            Map<String, Integer> currentlyOwned = threads.get(t);
            if(currentlyOwned == null){
                threads.put(t, new HashMap<String, Integer>(permits));
            }
            else{
                HashMap<String, Integer> totalOwned = new HashMap<String, Integer>(permits);
                for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : permits.entrySet()){
                    totalOwned.put(e.getKey(), 
                            e.getValue() 
                            + (totalOwned.get(e.getKey()) == null ? 0 : currentlyOwned.get(e.getKey())));
                }
                threads.put(t, totalOwned);
            }
        }
        finally{
            operationLock.release();            
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Released " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    /** Attempts to release the given amounts of the given permits.
     * Won't release more permits for any identifier than this currently owns.
     * @param permits               - the permits to release.
     * @throws InterruptedException - see Semaphore.acquire
     */
    public void release(Map<String, Integer> permits) throws InterruptedException{
        try{
            operationLock.acquire();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Acquired " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

            //Check to see if this thread has any permits at all
            if(! threads.containsKey(t))
                return;

            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : permits.entrySet()){
                Semaphore s = semaphores.get(e.getKey());
                if(s == null){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Permit Name " + e.getKey() + " Not in " + this);
                }
                int has = threads.get(t).containsKey(e.getKey()) ? threads.get(t).get(e.getKey()) : 0;
                int toRemove = Math.min(e.getValue(), has);
                s.release(toRemove);
                threads.get(t).put(e.getKey(), has - toRemove);
            }
            if(DEBUG){
                System.out.println("\nReleasing " + t);
                System.out.println(threads.toString().replaceAll("},", "}\n"));
            }


            //Ok, notify a thread wanting to acquire
            synchronized(operationLock){
                operationLock.notify();
            }
        }finally{
            operationLock.release();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Released " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    /** Releases all permits this currently owns for all identifiers within this Semaphore Group
     * @throws InterruptedException - see Semaphore.acquire
     */
    public void releaseAll() throws InterruptedException{
        try{
            operationLock.acquire();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Acquired " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            if(! threads.containsKey(t)) return;
            HashMap<String, Integer> permits = new HashMap<String, Integer>(threads.get(t));
            operationLock.release();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Released " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            release(permits);
        }finally{
            operationLock.release();
            if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Released " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }

    /** Returns the permits (by identifier) this SemaphoreGroup still has available. */
    public Map<String, Integer> getAvailablePermits(){
        HashMap<String, Integer> available = new HashMap<>();
        for(Entry<String, Semaphore> e : semaphores.entrySet()){
            available.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().availablePermits());
        }
        return available;
    }

    /** Returns the set of valid identifying strings for this semaphore group */
    public Set<String> getIdentifyingStrings(){
        return semaphores.keySet();
    }

    /** Returns the available permits out of the total as the toString */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        Map<String, Integer> available = getAvailablePermits();
        String s = "{";
        for(Entry<String, Integer> e : permits.entrySet()){
            s += e.getKey() + "=" + available.get(e.getKey()) + "/" + e.getValue() + ", ";
        }
        return s.substring(0, s.length() - 2) + "}";
    }
}
```

Runnable companion:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ThreadRunner extends JFrame {

    private static LinkedList<Worker> threads;
    private static SemaphoreGroup semaphore;
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> totalPermits;

    public ThreadRunner(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new InfoPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        repaint();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    static class InfoPanel extends JPanel{

        public InfoPanel(){
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
            int x = 20;
            int y = 20;
            g2d.drawString("Available: " + semaphore.toString(), x, y);
            y += 50;
            for(Worker t : threads){
                if(t.working) g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                else    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.drawString(t.getName() + "-" + t.status + " : " + t.job.toString(), x, y);
                y += 25;
                if(! t.working) g2d.drawString("Next: " + t.nextJob.toString(), x + 150, y);
                y += 35;
            }
        }
    }

    static class Worker extends Thread{

        private volatile String status;
        private boolean working;
        private HashMap<String, Integer> job = new HashMap<>();
        private HashMap<String, Integer> nextJob = new HashMap<>();
        private int jobIndex;
        private static final int WORK_TIME = 2000;


        public Worker(int i){
            super("Worker " + i);
            jobIndex = 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                createNextJob();
                while(true){
                    createNextJob();
                    HashMap<String, Integer> aJob = nextJob;
                    semaphore.acquire(aJob);
                    job = aJob;
                    working = true;

                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                        Thread.sleep(WORK_TIME / 10);
                        status = ((i + 1) * 10) + "% done of Job " + jobIndex;
                    }

                    semaphore.releaseAll();
                    working = false;
                    job.clear();

                    jobIndex++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        private void createNextJob(){
            nextJob = new HashMap<>();
            nextJob.put("Bronze", (int)(totalPermits.get("Bronze") * Math.random()));
            nextJob.put("Silver", (int)(totalPermits.get("Silver") * Math.pow(Math.random(), 2)));
            nextJob.put("Gold", (int)(totalPermits.get("Gold") * Math.pow(Math.random(), 3)));
            nextJob.put("Platinum", (int)(totalPermits.get("Platinum") * Math.pow(Math.random(), 4)));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return getName();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        totalPermits = new HashMap<>();
        totalPermits.put("Bronze", 15);
        totalPermits.put("Silver", 10);
        totalPermits.put("Gold", 5);
        totalPermits.put("Platinum", 2);

        semaphore = new SemaphoreGroup(totalPermits);
        threads = new LinkedList<Worker>();

        final int NUMB_WORKERS = 5;
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMB_WORKERS; i++){
            threads.add(new Worker(i));
        }

        ThreadRunner tr = new ThreadRunner();

        //Start worker threads
        for(Worker w : threads){
            w.start();
        }

        //Monitor gui in main thread
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tr.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete, working, contrived example that I believe fulfills the outlined requirements.

It tracks the total number of resources available in Semaphores, the actual resources in BlockingQueues and tasks in BlockingQueues.

If it's unable to acquire the required resources for a task immediately, it resubmits the task to the back of the Queue (this could be done other ways, but in this example it's using a bounded thread pool of workers so you wouldn't necessarily want them to wait until the resources are available as this could potentially prevent parallelization of other tasks that may be able to run immediately)

```
package so.thread.resources;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MultiResourcesMain {

  public static int numManagers = 5;
  public static int numProgrammers = 15;
  public static int numTesters = 5;

  public static Semaphore managersLease = new Semaphore(numManagers);
  public static Semaphore programmersLease = new Semaphore(numProgrammers);
  public static Semaphore testersLease = new Semaphore(numTesters);

  public static BlockingQueue<Manager> managers = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Manager>();
  public static BlockingQueue<Programmer> programmers = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Programmer>();
  public static BlockingQueue<Tester> testers = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Tester>();

  public static Random rand = new Random();

  public static BlockingQueue<Task> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  public static Object resourceLock = new Object();

  public static AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

  public static AtomicInteger tasksRun = new AtomicInteger(0);
  public static AtomicInteger resubmits = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // prime the resources
    for (int i = 0; i < numManagers; i++) {
      managers.add(new Manager());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; i++) {
      programmers.add(new Programmer());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numTesters; i++) {
      testers.add(new Tester());
    }

    int numTasks = 100;
    int managersRandLimit = numManagers + 1;
    int programmersRandLimit = numProgrammers + 1;
    int testersRandLimit = numTesters + 1;

    // generate tasks to execute with random resource requirements
    for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
      tasks.add(new Task(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new TaskResources(rand.nextInt(managersRandLimit), rand.nextInt(programmersRandLimit), rand.nextInt(testersRandLimit))));
    }

    // spin up worker threads
    int numWorkers = 10;
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numWorkers);
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
      taskExecutor.submit(new Worker());
    }

    while (tasksRun.get() < numTasks) {
      Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    running.set(false);

    taskExecutor.shutdown();
    taskExecutor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println(String.format("Done, ran %d tasks and resubmitted %d tasks due to insufficient resources at acquire time", tasksRun.get(), resubmits.get()));


  }

  public static class Worker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (running.get()) {
        try {
          Task task = tasks.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          if (null != task) {
            if (acquireResources(task.resources)) {
              runTask(task);
              releaseResources(task.resources);
            } else {
              // couldn't execute task now, returning to task queue
              System.out.println(String.format("[%s :: %s] !!! Couldn't acquire resources for Task %s, resubmitting",
                Thread.currentThread().getName(), new Date(), task.id));
              tasks.add(task);
              resubmits.getAndIncrement();
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      System.out.println(String.format("[%s :: %s] >>> Thread shutdown",
        Thread.currentThread().getName(), new Date()));
    }
  }

  public static void runTask(Task task) {
    Date now = new Date();
    long elapsed = now.getTime() - task.created.getTime();
    System.out.println(String.format("[%s :: %s] *** Running task with %d managers, %d programmers & %d testers, waited %d millis to execute for id %s",
      Thread.currentThread().getName(), now, task.resources.managers, task.resources.programmers, task.resources.testers, elapsed, task.id));
    tasksRun.getAndIncrement();
  }

  public static void releaseResources(TaskResources res) {
    synchronized (resourceLock) {
      managersLease.release(res.managers);
      programmersLease.release(res.programmers);
      testersLease.release(res.testers);
    }
  }

  public static boolean acquireResources(TaskResources res) {
    synchronized (resourceLock) {

      boolean acquiredManagers = false;
      boolean acquiredProgrammers = false;
      boolean acquiredTesters = false;

      acquiredManagers = managersLease.tryAcquire(res.managers);
      if (acquiredManagers) {
        acquiredProgrammers = programmersLease.tryAcquire(res.programmers);
        if (acquiredProgrammers) {
          acquiredTesters = testersLease.tryAcquire(res.testers);
        }
      }

      if (acquiredManagers && acquiredProgrammers && acquiredTesters) {
        return true;
      } else {
        // return unused resources
        if (acquiredProgrammers) {
          programmersLease.release(res.programmers);
        }
        if (acquiredManagers) {
          managersLease.release(res.managers);
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  public abstract static class Person {

  }

  public static class Manager extends Person {

  }

  public static class Programmer extends Person {

  }

  public static class Tester extends Person {

  }

  public static class Task {
    public String id;
    public TaskResources resources;
    public Date created = new Date();

    public Task(String id, TaskResources resources) {
      this.id = id;
      this.resources = resources;
    }
  }

  public static class TaskResources {
    public int managers;
    public int programmers;
    public int testers;

    public TaskResources(int managers, int programmers, int testers) {
      this.managers = managers;
      this.programmers = programmers;
      this.testers = testers;
    }
  }
}
```